# How to train my neural network properly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, feed-forward

My neural network solving a nonlinear problem, but the testing loss is very high. When I use a neural network without hidden layer the testing loss is lower than with hidden layer but also high. Someone know why? and how I can improve the loss?

```
#data

    train_X = data_in[0:9001, :]
    train_Y = data_out[0:9001, :]
    test_X = data_in[9000:10001, :]
    test_Y = data_out[9000:10001, :
    n = train_X.shape[1] 
    m = train_X.shape[0]
    d = train_Y.shape[1]  
    l = test_X.shape[0]

#parameters

    trainX = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, n])
    trainY = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, d])
    testX = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [l, n])
    testY = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [l, d])
    def multilayer(trainX, h1, h2, hout, b1, b2, bout):
        layer_1 = tf.matmul(trainX, h1) + b1
        layer_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_1)
        layer_2 = tf.matmul(layer_1, h2) + b2
        layer_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_2)
        out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, hout) + bout
        return out_layer
    h1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n, n_hidden_1]))
    h2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2]))
    hout = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_hidden_2, d]))
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_hidden_1]))
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_hidden_2]))
    bout = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([d]))
    pred = multilayer(trainX, h1, h2, hout, b1, b2, bout)
    predtest = multilayer(testX, h1, h2, hout, b1, b2, bout)
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred - trainY, 2)) / (batch_size)
    losstest = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(predtest - testY, 2)) / (l)
    optimizer = 
    tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)

# Initializing the variables

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    a = np.linspace(0, m - batch_size, m / batch_size, dtype=np.int32)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        for i in (a):
            x = train_X[i:i + batch_size, :]
            y = train_Y[i:i + batch_size, :]
            for epoch in range(training_epochs):
                sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={trainX: np.asarray(x), trainY: 
                          np.asarray(y)})
                c = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={trainX: np.asarray(x), trainY: 
                            np.asarray(y)})
                print("Batch:", '%04d' % (i / batch_size + 1), "Epoch:", '%04d'%
                      (epoch + 1), "loss=", "{:.9f}".format(c))
# Testing
    print("Testing... (Mean square loss Comparison)")
    testing_loss = sess.run(losstest, feed_dict={testX: np.asarray(test_X), 
    testY: np.asarray(test_Y)})
    pred_y_vals = sess.run(predtest, feed_dict={testX: test_X})
    print("Testing loss=", testing_loss)
```

Comment: Your training is wrong, I think. You inverted epochs and batches. Which means you're training on the same batch several times then switching to a new batch.

Comment: As other people have already mentioned, your epoch and beaches are inverted most likely. Also, having a heavy loss in the test means overfitting the data. Try using regularization if you are seeing the same issue even after changing the loops.

Comment: Can you recommend on best regularization to this network?And how I can to do it in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your training loop, you're iterating on the epochs before iterating on the batches. Which means that your network will be trained  several times (`training_epochs` times) on the same batch and then go on to the next batch. It will never come back on a batch it's seen before.

Intuitively, I would say that your network is heavily overfitting on the last batch it's seen during training. Which explains the high loss during testing.

Invert the two loops in your training and you should be fine.